# Avoid long lists of arguments in constructor service Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I've been using Symfony to develop my web applications but I keep running into one problem. I always end up with too much clutter in the constructor of my services since I want to be able to unit test my services properly.

### Theoretical use case

Let's say I need a service which allows me to process an XML file and save it's contents into the database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<users>
    <user>
        <id>1234</id>
        <username>Example User</username>
        <email>user@example.com</email>
        <usergroup>
            <id>567</id>
            <name>Example User Group</name>
        </usergroup>
        <permissions>
            <item>ALLOWED_TO_CREATE</item>
            <item>ALLOWED_TO_UPDATE</item>
            <item>ALLOWED_TO_DELETE</item>
            <item>ALLOWED_TO_view</item>
        </permissions>
    </user>
</users>
```

Already quite a few things come to mind which you need to inject into this service:

- DomCrawler (to read the XML file)
- UserRepository (to get existing Users)
- UserGroupRepository (to get existing UserGroups)
- PermissionsRepository (to get existing permissions)
- EntityManager (to persist en flush new/updated objects)

The real XML file I'm working with contains much more data which requires me to inject many more repositories and other services which handle certain logic.

### Solution 1: Use Doctrine service

Inject the Doctrine service directory into my service and get the repositories via `$doctrine->getRepository(User::class)`

**Pros**

- Significatly reduces the amount of arguments

**Cons**

- Unit testing becomes a lot harder since I don't know what the service accesses anymore which renders them useless

### Solution 2: Use setter injection

Remove all services and repositories from the constructor and create setter methods and call then in the services.yml

```
services:
  AppBundle\Service\MyImportService:
    calls:
      - [setUserRepository, ['@app.user_repository']]
```

**Pros**

- Arguably easier to read

**Cons**

- More code
- Services no longer mandatory, optional validation may be required

### Question

What are solutions to make the argument lists in my services more maintainable in terms of readability and ability to unit test?

Is it even considered bad practise to have a long list of arguments?

Comment: Consider for example combining UserRespository, UserGroupRepository and PermissionRepository into some sort of UserFinder service.  With all the individual services you are injecting, I think you may be fooling yourself if you think you are doing proper unit testing.  And one trick is to add persist/flush to your repositories which often avoids the need for dealing with the entity manager directly.

Comment: Might also look at the notion of aggregate root from the domain driven design folks.  Right now you have a mental image that User UserGroup and Permission are all individual objects but in fact, within this particular design context, all you really have is a more complex user object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having many arguments in your constructor is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) called [Constructor Over-Injection](https://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/constructor-over-injection-smell-ndash-follow-up/). This code smell is often an indication of the class taking on too much responsibility, meaning it violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP). SRP violations cause maintenance problems, which is why you should keep a close eye on them.

Although refactoring to Property Injection might reduce the number of constructor arguments and therefore the amount of clutter in the constructor, it *does not* solve the underlying problem, which is that this class is becoming too complex. Property Injection is therefore **not** a solution to Constructor Over-Injection.

The solution to this code smell is to reduce the complexity of the class at hand. There are many ways to do this, but a very common approach is the [Facade Services refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/):

> Facade Service [is] closely related to [Parameter Objects](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html), but the main difference is that a Parameter Object only moves the parameters to a common root, while a Facade Service **hides the aggregate behavior behind a new abstraction**. While the Facade Service may start its life as a result of a pure mechanistic refactoring, it often turns out that the extracted behavior represents a Domain Concept in its own right.

#### Pros:

- Reduces the class' complexity and thereby solves the underlying problem
- Prevents depending on the Doctrine service (which is an application of the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/))
- Introduces new concepts and improvements to the Domain language.
- Prevents property injection (since property injection causes [Temporal Coupling](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/))

#### Cons:

- Facade Services might not be the right refactoring. Many alternatives exist, such as [Domain Events](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html) and [Decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

These are topics that [Mark](https://blog.ploeh.dk/about/) and I discuss in our book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://mng.bz/BYNl). [Section 6.1](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-6/section-6-1), for instance, specifically talks about refactoring from Constructor Over-Injection to Façade Services or Domain Events, while [chapters 9](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-9/) and [10](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-10/) do a deep dive into using Decorators. Do note though, that the book's examples are written in C#, and focuses on statically typed, object-oriented languages. While there are a few chapters that focus entirely around .NET technology, you'll find most of the other parts suitable for other languages such as modern versions of PHP as well.